# Windows Phone 7 and HTML5?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7

I am interesting: whether Windows Phone 7 will support HTML5 web sites or not? As I know IE on PC supports it only with Google's [plugin](http://code.google.com/intl/en/chrome/chromeframe/) :D What do you know about Windows Phone 7 internet browser "features"?

Thank you!;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From like 10 press releases in aug:

> Microsoft says that there is no plan currently to bring HTML 5 support to Internet Explorer Mobile. The mobile browser, which has been re-written for the next-generation operating system, is based in large part off of the desktop editions of Internet Explorer 7 and 8; Internet Explorer 9 for Windows does support HTML 5.

It's a bummer and hopefully they will shoehorn ie9 in there, but for now don't count on it.

One link from MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/4233a7b5-6b70-4318-96f1-6683e2c38c03

> Where the picture gets sllightly nuanced is that the Mobile IE team have announced that they've implemented some new features in terms of CSS tags andJavaScript functions, so while the base browser model is IE 7.0 there'll be some extras (see here). Hopefully they'll add more over time.

Answer (score 2):

IE 7 Mobile is what has made it onto the v1 product.

You might be aware already that IE9 desktop is leading the way for IE with HTML5 compliance.

It would be nice (and perhaps logical) if an update to IE on the phone sees IE9 brought across, but I haven't seen an official confirmation of this direction at the moment.