# Windows phone 7 and HTML5

Tags: html, html5-video, windows-phone, html5-audio

I'm completely new to Windows Phone and the Windows galaxy in general as far as programming goes. For a project of a phone app that has to run on a windows phone, I started exploring the resources and I have some questions.

One of the problems I encountered is that things change very quickly. For example, answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209497/windows-phone-7-and-html5) say that browsers in Windows Phone will most likely not support HTML5. However, there are many online tutorials (for instance [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features)) introducing ASP.NET MVC 4 and how it is appropriate for mobile apps.

I would personally like to go the "HTML5+javascript" way instead of learning how to develop with Silverlight, which apparently has been discontinued by Microsoft. However, my first concern is evidently to be able to create an application that works!

So with that in mind, my questions are the following:

- My impression is that HTML5+JS is being introduced in replacement of Silverlight and will be more used in the future. Is that correct?
- Knowing that I have to build an app which should be able to play videos and audio, record audio, and connect to a library to do some speech processing in the background, should I use Silverlight or can I try using ASP.NET MVC 4? (From what I gather, Silverlight would be better than XNA)
- Are there limitations to using HTML5+JS as compared to Silverlight or the other way around?
- Can you package a web app (i.e. using HTML5+JS) to be used locally on the phone if there is no access to a distant server?

Any specific pointers or answers on these specific issues will be more than welcome! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, Windows Phone 7.1 does not support full HTML5+JS as a replacement for Silverlight. In Windows 8 (NOT the next version of windows phone, but the next version of Microsoft's desktop OS), HTML5+JS is presented as an *alternative* to using XAML and C# (it's a little confusing because on Windows 8, "metro" apps do not run Silverlight, but they still operate using XAML and C#). But that's neither here nor there... To summarily answer your question(s): In the phone's browser, there is very limited HTML5 capability.

From what you've described, you definitely want to use Silverlight for your Windows Phone app. The answer to *that* part of your question has never changed, Silverlight from the beginning of WP7 would be your best option. XNA is exclusively designed for gaming development.

**To answer all of your questions, point by point:**

> My impression is that HTML5+JS is being introduced in replacement of
>   Silverlight and will be more used in the future. Is that correct?

This has not been confirmed (as of this post), but speculation is that this will be the case in some future release of the OS (no word on when that may be). But no, this is not currently an option, and there is no promise from Microsoft that it ever will be.

> Knowing that I have to build an app which should be able to play
>   videos and audio, record audio, and connect to a library to do some
>   speech processing in the background, should I use Silverlight or can I
>   try using ASP.NET MVC 4? (From what I gather, Silverlight would be
>   better than XNA)

Silverlight. Silverlight. Silverlight. :) ASP.NET + MVC will not work. XNA is intended to be used for building games. Attempting to build more standard user interfaces using it would give you a migraine to say the least, and would not look anywhere near good.

> Are there limitations to using HTML5+JS as compared to Silverlight or the other way around?

and

> Can you package a web app (i.e. using HTML5+JS) to be used locally on the phone if there is > no access to a distant server?

As answered above, there is no way to do this on the phone.

As for pointers on all of this. I strongly encourage you to simply google (or bing if you're into that kind of thing) "getting started with windows phone" or "windows phone tutorials". Best source I could point you to is the [Windows Phone Developer](http://developer.windowsphone.com) website. It's got some great tutorials that don't assume you know lots about windows phone. Best to get this material from Microsoft. It'll be more reliable, more well written, and ultimatly more useful. I've been writing Windows Phone apps since before the phone was released, and I still use it for learning the basics of something new. Great place.

Comment: great answer, thanks! In the meantime I indeed came to the same conclusions as you (Silverlight, Silverlight, Silverlight :). It was a lot of reading (still is!) but I'm getting a clearer picture.

Comment: glad to hear it! Silverlight is absolutely incredible. Very fun and easy to get a lot of very pretty stuff done very quickly. I *highly* recommend both <a href="http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/blog/">Jeff Wilcox' blog</a> (he used to work on the Windows Phone team), as well as <a href="http://windowsphonegeek.com/">Windows Phone Geek</a> as great places to go when you get stuck with something. Inevitably google searches for problems will bring you to either of those two places, or of course to this wonderful site :)